# In Java code, need to figure out how to get back to the main menu after doing one of the options in the menu?

Tags: java, menu

I am working on Java code. I have a menu, the user selects an option, does something in the option then returns to the menu until the exit is selected. I'm not sure how to get it to go back to the menu.

Here is what I have:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Lisa Hergert
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MathTutor {

    //Create scanner for user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare variables
        int choice;
        Random generator = new Random();

        public MathTutor () {
            choice = 0;
        }

        public int getQuestionType() {
            while (choice < 1 || choice >3) {
                System.out.println("Math Tutor");
                System.out.println("\t1) Addition problem");
                System.out.println("\t2) Subtraction problem");
                System.out.println("\t3) Quit");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice (1 - 3): ");
                choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
                    System.out.println("You must choose a number from 1-3");
                }
            } 
            return choice;
            }

    public void askQuestions () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int num1 = genRandomNum();
            int num2 = genRandomNum();
            int max = choice;
            if (max == 3) {
                max = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
            }
            switch (max) {
                case 1: addition(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case 2: subtraction(num1, num2);
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Error");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

public int genRandomNum() {
    return (int)generator.nextInt(1000);
}

public void addition(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 > num2) {
        System.out.printf("%5d\n", num1);
        System.out.printf("+ %3d\n", num2);
        System.out.println("-------");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%5d\n", num2);
        System.out.printf("+ %3d\n", num1);
        System.out.println("-------");
    }
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
        System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + sum);
    }
}

public void subtraction (int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 > num2) {
        System.out.printf("%5d\n", num1);
        System.out.printf("- %3d\n", num2);
        System.out.println("-------");
    int diff = num1 - num2;
    int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (num1 - num2 == answer) {
            System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + diff);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%5d\n", num2);
        System.out.printf("- %3d\n", num1);
        System.out.println("-------");
    int diff = num2 - num1;
    int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (num2 - num1 == answer) {
            System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + diff);
        }
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MathTutor tutor = new MathTutor();

    int choice = tutor.getQuestionType();

    tutor.askQuestions();

    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You know the `int choice` in your main method will shadow the `choice` class variable. Better change that to `choice = tutor.getQuestionType();`.

Comment: I did that and Netbeans shows me there is an error, "non-static variable choice cannot be referenced from a static content", so that doesn't work

Comment: An easy solution would be to make it `static`. You could also create a "second main method", and call it from main with `tutor.main2();`. Then you'll be inside an instance method and you'll have access to instance / non-static variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Lisa Hergert
 */
public class MathTutor {

        //Create scanner for user input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Declare variables
            int choice;
            Random generator = new Random();

            public MathTutor () {
                choice = 0;
            }

            public int getQuestionType() {
                while (choice < 1 || choice >3) {
                    System.out.println("Math Tutor");
                    System.out.println("\t1) Addition problem");
                    System.out.println("\t2) Subtraction problem");
                    System.out.println("\t3) Quit");
                    System.out.println("Enter your choice (1 - 3): ");
                    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
                        System.out.println("You must choose a number from 1-3");
                    }
                } 
                return choice;
                }

        public void askQuestions () {
                int num1 = genRandomNum();
                int num2 = genRandomNum();
                int max = choice;
                if (max == 3) {
                    max = (int)(Math.random() * 3+3);
                }
                switch (max) {
                    case 1: addition(num1, num2);
                        break;
                    case 2: subtraction(num1, num2);
                        break;
                    default: System.out.println("Thank you for your time.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }


    public int genRandomNum() {
        return (int)generator.nextInt(1000);
    }

    public void addition(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 > num2) {
            System.out.printf("%5d\n", num1);
            System.out.printf("+ %3d\n", num2);
            System.out.println("-------");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%5d\n", num2);
            System.out.printf("+ %3d\n", num1);
            System.out.println("-------");
        }
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
            System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + sum);
        }

        MathTutor tutor = new MathTutor();

        int choice = tutor.getQuestionType();

        tutor.askQuestions();
    }

    public void subtraction (int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 > num2) {
            System.out.printf("%5d\n", num1);
            System.out.printf("- %3d\n", num2);
            System.out.println("-------");
        int diff = num1 - num2;
        int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (num1 - num2 == answer) {
                System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + diff);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%5d\n", num2);
            System.out.printf("- %3d\n", num1);
            System.out.println("-------");
        int diff = num2 - num1;
        int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (num2 - num1 == answer) {
                System.out.println("Good job, you got it right!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good try, the correct answer is: " + diff);
            }
        }

        MathTutor tutor = new MathTutor();

        int choice = tutor.getQuestionType();

        tutor.askQuestions();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MathTutor tutor = new MathTutor();

        int choice = tutor.getQuestionType();

        tutor.askQuestions();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but can't you just loop all the functionality?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MathTutor tutor = new MathTutor();

  int choice = tutor.getQuestionType();
  while(choice != 3) {
    tutor.askQuestions();
    choice = tutor.getQuestionType();
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than how I did it, but it was due at a weird time today, so I turned it in last night